# Program wanted to analyse/send/combine reports and feedback

Tags: windows, email, automation, microsoft-excel

My main job at my company is to analyse reports.
I receive them in an csv file, with additional information such as, who sent them and from where.
My normal workflow is to read the reports, create a new column in excel where I put the name of the responsible department (they need to give the feedback on the reports).

Then, at the end of the week, I create a new excel with all the reports for 1 department (so if I have assigned 30 different departments that week, I need to create 30 different excels). Right now, I use a macro in excel to split the main excel based on the value in the column to split the excel. After the splitting is complete, I send the excels one by one to the departments via mail.

After a couple of days, I receive the feedback of the departments, I put them in my main excel for reference, and then I sent the feedback one by one via mail to the person who created the reports.

As you can imagine, this is a lot of work. I figure that there are ways to automate this process. so now for the question: does somebody know  a way or an existing program through which I can make this process easier and save a lot of time?

Hopefully someone can help me!

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: perhaps some kind of ticket-/bugtracking-system may fit this workflow?

Answer (score 0):

[Pentaho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentaho) Data Integration is designed for such workflows.

Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) can read emails from an email server, parse CSV and Excel files, mix data in any possible way, write files in many formats, and send emails.

Design your workflow by drag-and-dropping elements and configuring them in the PDI editor. Examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Jobs can be [scheduled](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.2/Products/Data_Integration/Schedule_Perspective) to run everyday, or more if needed. I guess you would have an everyday job and a monthly job.

[image]

Gratis and open source.